# can't launch eclipse ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed eclipse using apt-get install eclipse. however when trying edit the eclipse.desktop, I realized that I didn't know the path to put for Exec. I then started to look for the eclipse directory in the /opt/ which was not there. now the question is where could this folder be.
from the software center i could see that eclipse is installed but when I click on eclipse icon in the dash. there is no response(no lauching of eclipse). does anyone has an idea of what is going on.

Comment: dpkg -S eclipse or dpkg -L on what your installed eclipse package is called

Comment: this shows a lot of information on locations but the problem is that some of those info seem not to be true(at least to me). for instance there is info saying that there is an eclipse folder in /usr/lib/ which is not true. this confuses me

Answer (score 0):

```
Run the Genome code from Terminal(Alt+ctrl+T)

**gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/.local/share/applications/**
A dialog box will appear.
```

1. For Name: you'll probably want to name it "Eclipse".
2. For Command: browse to where the Eclipse executable is located.
3. For Comment: something like "Eclipse IDE" should do.
4. For the icon, click the springboard icon, then navigate to the folder where the executable is located and select icon.xpm.

   Click Okay. You've now made the launcher icon. All that's left is to put it in the launcher bar.
   Open the folder ~/.local/share/applications/ . You may need to hit ctrl-h to show the hidden .local folder.
   Drag the Eclipse launcher icon you just made onto the launcher.
   Done!